# Get Each Digits of Number with Using Loops in C++

Tags: c++, beginner

I need a program same as I wrote but using loops. (if else for etc.) .  Program is that enter a number and get each digits of number like that: number is 123456. I'm beginner, I can't create the logic and can't combine loops. Can anybody help me about that situation?

```
1.digits is 6
2.digits is 5
3.digits is 4
4.digits is 3
5.digits is 2
6.digits is 1
7.digits is 0
8.digits is 0
9.digits is 0
```

.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main() 
    {
        int number,first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth;
        
        cout<< "Enter a number (<999999999): " << endl;
        
        cin>>number;
        
        first = number%10;
        second = number/10%10;
        third = number/100%10;
        fourth = number/1000%10;
        fifth = number/10000%10;
        sixth = number/100000%10;
        seventh = number/1000000%10;
        eighth = number/10000000%10;
        ninth = number/100000000%10;
        
        cout<<"1. digit is"<<" "<<first<<endl;
        cout<<"2. digit is"<<" "<<second<<endl;
        cout<<"3. digit is"<<" "<<third<<endl;
        cout<<"4. digit is"<<" "<<fourth<<endl;
        cout<<"5. digit is"<<" "<<fifth<<endl;
        cout<<"6. digit is"<<" "<<sixth<<endl;
        cout<<"7. digit is"<<" "<<seventh<<endl;
        cout<<"8. digit is"<<" "<<eighth<<endl;
        cout<<"9. digit is"<<" "<<ninth<<endl;
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Unfortunately, we don't write code to order, we simply _review_ code you've written, and might make suggestions that improve it. Depending on your problem, another site of the [StackExchange network](//stackexchange.com/) can help you. Please see our [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: BTW, once you have it working as you want, please do ask for a review, as you have some bad habits (`using namespace std`, for one, and `std::endl` instead of plain newline, for another) that you could improve on.

Comment: @TobySpeight - I am not sure that there is any site which writes code to order.  StackOverflow can help with actual programming problems, but only when the poster has tried something and is running into trouble.

Comment: Can I suggest that you try an online tutorial first?  Then, once you have tried to write the code with loops, if you are still having problems, you can post a question on Stack Overflow.  If you search "C++ tutorial loops", you should find several options which should help you get started.  Good luck!

Comment: I subscribe to "Ask a 5th grader" what something means and to the average 5th grader, the first digit would be the leftmost digit or greatest non-zero power of 10.  And that same 5th grader would tell me that I took a long winded approach to tell you I think the digits are presented in the wrong order.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this was closed.  I suggested the OP post the code here (it was on SO) to get feedback on his bad habits etc.  His mistake was including the full text of the original request for help as well; the code _does compile_ and _does run_ as it is (without loops), so it should be just fine to post here so we can tell him not to use `using namespace std;` and all the usual stuff.  The "question" should be replaced with a note saying this code was referred, rather than being closed.

Answer (score 3):

I suggested you post here; it qualifies as it is working/compiling code.  In the original post on Stack Overflow people might answer you on explaining how to do looping.  Here, we just review what you wrote.

`using namespace std;`
Don't do that.  There are posts here explaining why not in detail.

`int number,first,second,third,fourth,fifth,sixth,seventh,eighth,ninth;`
You put this as the very first line in the function.
Don't declare all variables at the top!  Declare them when you are ready to use them and only when you are ready to initialize them.  Keep them in the smallest scope necessary.

Also, in C++ we generally don't list a bunch of variables in one declaration like that.  Of course, the larger design issue is that `first` through `ninth` are not actually needed, but that's not the subject here.

`cout<< "Enter a number (<999999999): " << endl;`
Don't use `endl`.  Rather, just output a `'\n'` character.  Here, that can be included in the string with the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

### Organize the data and access by index

The code as it is written is readable and does the job, but it is cumbersome and not easy to make more flexible.  I think this is what you are getting at when asking about loops.

First of all, when you want a group of common variables, and you find yourself using names like "first", "second", and so on, take this as a hint to use some kind of container for them, and access them by index.  If the size is fixed, you can use an array:

```
const int size = 0;
int digits[size];
```

If you do not have a fixed number of digits, use a vector:

```
 std::vector<int> digits;
```

Then you can add the digits as you extract them, however many they are.

Using an array or a vector will simplify the code and make it much easier to modify later.  It will also make it possible for you to use a loop, which is your original question.  When you can access each digit by an index, rather than a name, you can use a loop to do what is needed for each digit, accessing the array by index (or iterator, in the case of the vector).

Once you are doing this in a loop, you can improve the code further by stopping when you have no more digits (after the division, you are left with zero

### Avoid 'magic numbers'

In general, avoid hardcoded numbers like `999999999` or `100000`.  For the former, if you use a constant instead of a hardcoded number, it is easier to modify later.  Often limits like this are used in more than one place in the code, and you won't want to hunt for them and change all of them later.  Note that `100000` and its friends in your code are being used as multiples of 10 -- you can calculate them as you go -- put the 10 into a variable and multiply again for the next digit (this is another hint which should help you convert this to use a loop).

### Avoid polluting your namespace, especially with `std`

```
using namespace std;
```

`std` defines common functionality with quite generic names.  The namespace limits the scope of the name, avoiding possible name conflicts; see [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for more details.

### Take control of i/o

Decide when you want to flush the buffer, when you have a unit of output.  std::endl does not only write a newline, it flushes the buffer.  In this little program, that may not matter, but it is better practice to *choose* when to do this, or minimize it when possible.  Writing to the screen, or a file, etc., is much much slower than writing to RAM (where the buffer is).

If you just need the newline, use `'\n'`.  The buffer will be flushed when it is full, or the program ends, etc.; in short, when it must be.  See [this question and its higher rated answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n?rq=1) for more information.

Comment: Thank you to  Toby Speight (and, later, JDługosz) for mentioning the issue with std::endl.  I was not aware of it and had to look up why; I learned something new; I'm just sharing what I learned along with what I had wanted to say!

Comment: `const int size = 0;` should be `constexpr size_t size = 0`.